# ClientDataset reordens table from Datasetprovider in datasnap,on strings that starts with '

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, datasnap, tclientdataset, firemonkey-fm2

On my Datasnap server I query some records and order them by a stringfield.
Strings that start with ' are in front, this is default behaviour. (the database is interbase)

```
'Aaa
'Bbb
Aaa
Bbb
```

When i use a tClientdataset and a TDSProviderConnection on the client and connect to the TSQLDataset trough a TDatasetProvider the table on the client looks like this:

```
'Aaa
aaa
'Bbb
bbb
```

How to stop this? I am sure the order is correct in the TSQLdataset on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer right after posting, but ill leave it here.

It is an option of the TDatasetProvider

```
poRetainServerOrder : True
```

very strange that this is not the default behaviour.